# What is the logic behind this how it is working?

Tags: java, deobfuscation

I have read the some tricky interview question i have seen this i couldn't understand what is the logic behind this . Can some one explain ?

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
for(char c⁯‮h = 0; c⁯‮h < Character.MAX_VALUE; c⁯‮h++)
    if (Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c⁯‮h) && !Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c⁯‮h))
            System.out.printf("%04x <%s>%n", (int) c⁯‮h, "" + c⁯‮h);
    }
}
```

OutPut

```
0000 < >
0001 <>
0002 <>
0003 <>
0004 <>
0005 <>
0006 <>
0007 <>
0008 <>
000e <>
000f <>
0010 <>
0011 <>
0012 <>
0013 <>
0014 <>
0015 <>
0016 <>
0017 <>
....more rows
```

Comment: I'd post a compilable example first; this isn't even code yet. Looks like something is supposed to be in a string, but even then, something's missing.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  this is what the program it is .

Comment: I'd recommend you check the java documentation on the methods being used and then it should make sense.

Comment: @DaveNewton It compiles. http://ideone.com/iP3HWq

Comment: Because of the unprintable chars, which are invisible here. My point is that without doing analysis the question is non-sensical, and the OP did none of that.

Comment: Not a u-turn at all-what was missing was due diligence on the OP's part, at least IMO.

Comment: @DaveNewton not digilenge person like u con't understand at first sight . im beginner has no clue of what is going on . The question also raised by of the high reputation person(peter-lawrey) in SO . Unfortunately he didn't clearly explain. So i don't think it easy. if con't answer better quite . Don't  criticize no one knows everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this:

```
for(char c⁯‮h = 0; c⁯‮h < Character.MAX_VALUE; c⁯‮h++)
```

is the same as

```
for(char ch=0; ch< Character.MAX_VALUE; ch++)
```

but is written backwards.... so is a normal for loop